# Let's get critical: Jun 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Lifehacks Stack Exchange](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to easily clean dough remains after baking bread?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/how-to-easily-clean-dough-remains-after-baking-bread)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How can I open the window when it's dark outside without fearing that moths might fly in?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/how-can-i-open-the-window-when-its-dark-outside-without-fearing-that-moths-migh)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to keep change sorted in my pocket?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6679/how-to-keep-change-sorted-in-my-pocket)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Friendly way to get rid of screeching birds](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7093/friendly-way-to-get-rid-of-screeching-birds)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Ways to stop your Beach blanket from blowing away](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/ways-to-stop-your-beach-blanket-from-blowing-away)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the best way to clean a stove?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-a-stove)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Where should a fan be aimed for maximum cooling of a room with one opening?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6881/where-should-a-fan-be-aimed-for-maximum-cooling-in-a-room-with-1-opening)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Easy way to scan a book](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/easy-way-to-scan-a-book)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [How to remove tomato sauce stains from dishwasher?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6864/how-to-remove-tomato-sauce-stains-from-dishwasher)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [How to remove facial hairs in girls without threading/bleaching using natural products?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/how-to-remove-facial-hairs-in-girls-without-threading-bleaching-using-natural-pr)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the meta site and common questions, you see what I believe is also reflected in the questions and answers: *People have problems defining what is or needs a life hack, and it is hard to avoid conventional how to questions*.

Sadly, I don't see how we can improve answers, before the questions gets better. Combined with the low traffic issue, I think there is some reluctance to closing borderline question sometimes, which in turn lets lower quality questions through the filter.

Solutions? I'm not sure, but maybe one should either reconsider *opening up the scope somewhat*, as I'm not sure there is a large enough need for life hacks to warrant a site like this, or possibly it could help to *have a close reason related to people not doing their homework* and searching for the conventional solution before asking here.

Comment: While I agree the quality of this site is low, I disagree that we should broaden our scope. our scope is already broad enough as it is, not to mention poorly defined. The focus should be on narrowing the scope and better defining it, because "everyday problems" is  a horrible scope.